# Can I specify a custom decimal_point in PHP locale settings?

Tags: php, localization, locale

I am coding something for a region which speaks spanish and uses a `.` (dot, period) for a decimal point instead if a `,` (comma)

I am using dictionary files for translation and have successfuly set the locale to `es` and everything works fine, including translations, etc.

Except, in this region they don't use the comma for numeric decimal points.

ie I am getting `33,66` instead of `33.66`

How can I specify a custom `decimal_point` value for the current locale?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: you can use [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Comment: @Sammitch I don't want to set the value for a single number, I want to override the locale.

Comment: @Dagon I want to override the locale setting just for decimal points

Comment: still should work fine, what happened when you tried?